# Leitura de registro para inferir contador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, concorrência

Tenho um modelo chamado Request e esse modelo tem uma coluna chamada Number.

Esse Number tem a seguinte estrutura: ANO + CONTADOR.

Acontece que sempre que vou criar uma nova *request* eu pego a última *request* adicionada no banco de dados e a partir dela posso inferir o `Number` da nova *request*.

Por exemplo, se minha última *request* inserida tem `number = 20140001` então a próxima *request* terá `number = 20140002`.

O problema ocorre quando duas *requests* são geradas simultaneamente. Acontece que dois ou mais processos podem criar *requests*. Logo em cada processo desse o banco é acessado, eu verifico qual é a ultima *request* e gero uma nova. Acontece que de modo simultâneo os processos pegam a mesma *request* e consequentemente geram `Numbers` iguais.

Estou usando Entity Framework 5 e MVC 4. Como resolver isso?

Comment: Qual e' a base de dados?

Comment: Junior, você já resolveu este problema? Ainda precisa de ajuda?

Comment: é Sql server dcastro! Ainda não resolvi Andre. A resposta do dcastro não acho que está correta. Não quero um contador para a minha key.

Comment: Você precisa do número ANTES do insert no banco de dados, é isso?

Comment: Sim @iuristona.

Answer (score 1):

1. Tens que actualizar o esquema da BD, e alterar o campo `number` da tabela `Requests` para

   - chave primaria
   - *auto increment* - isto depende da BD. Em SQL Server, usa-se a keyword *Identity*
2. Adicionar o atributo `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` a' propriedade `Number` no codigo.

   ```
   public class Request
   {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
       public int Number {get; set;}
   }
   ```

Assim, a BD vai tratar de auto-incrementar o campo. E gracas as propriedades *ACID*, nao havera problemas de concurrencias.

---

Se nao quiseres/poderes usar autoincrement, acho que vais ter de implementar o teu proprio mecanismo, e isso nao é tarefa simples...

Ora bem, ja nao trabalho com bases de dados ha algum tempo, mas eu recomendo o seguinte:

- Criar uma tabela (ex: "NumberCounter") com uma só linha e uma só coluna (ex: "Count")

  ```
  ╔═══════╗
  ║ Count ║
  ╠═══════╣
  ║  2010 ║
  ╚═══════╝
  ```
- Quando quiseres incrementar & obter o próximo number, usa uma stored procedure que:

  1. Incrementa o valor de Count. Exemplo em "pseudo-codigo"/"pseudo-query": `INSERT INTO NumberCounter(Count) values((Select Count from NumberCounter) + 1);`
  2. Usa um *lock* na tabela, para impedir que outros increments sejam feitos em paralelo
  3. Retorna o valor actual de Count.

Espero que ajude.

Ler mais:
 [Understanding Locking in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Não quero um autoincrement...

Comment: @Junior posso perguntar porquê? Parece ser o ideal para essa situação..

Comment: @Junior, editei a minha resposta e forneci um rascunho de uma solução alternativa. Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Se você está utilizando *SQL Server 2012* você deveria utilizar uma `sequence`. O valor deve ser recuperado no momento em que o form é carregado.

Se seu banco não for *SQL Server 2012*, uma opção pra simular uma `sequence` está nesse [artigo](http://juliobattisti.com.br/artigos/windows/sequencesqlserver.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Para lidar com esse problema de concorrência, eu crio a entidade em questão e uma outra entidade de controle. Assim:

1- crio a entidade principal, neste caso: **Request**

```
public class Request
{
    public Guid RequestId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public int Number { get; set; }

    // demais propriedades necessárias
}
```

2- crio uma entidade de controle do número, tipo: **RequestCounter**

```
public class RequestCounter
{
    public Guid RequestCounterId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public int Number { get; set; } // no banco este campo será autoincrement

    public DateTime Dth { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

3- Na *Action* do **Controller**, eu chamo *ObterRequestCounter()* para obtenção do número.

```
public ActionResult Create(Request request)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        request.Number = ObterRequestCounter();

        _repository.Adicionar(request);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(request);
}
```

4- Crio o método privado onde adiciono um **RequestCounter** com o *RequestCounterId* gerado por mim (quando instancio) e depois faço a consulta utilizando-o para recuperar *Number*.

```
private int ObterRequestCounter()
{
    var requestCounter = new RequestCounter();

    _repository.AdicionarRequestCounter(requestCounter);

    var newNumber = _repository.ObterRequestCounterPorId
                                (requestCounter.RequestCounterId).Number;

    // concateno o ano com o novo número e depois retorno para número.  
    return Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year + newNumber.ToString());
}
```

Por causa do passo 4, não importa quantos usuário farão uma adição do **Request** ao mesmo tempo. Com o *RequestCounterId* do **RequestCounter** gerado no código (antes de ir para o banco), eu consigo recuperar qual foi o *Number* gerado automaticamente pelo banco sem concorrência.

No meu caso, a tabela do **RequestCounter** fica como histórico, mas se meu cliente em algum momento futuro decidir que registros antigos devam ser apagados, eu posso fazê-lo utilizando a propriedade *Dth* para isso.

É isso.